# window.pageYOffset vs document.documentElement.scrollTop

Tags: javascript

In Javascript `window.pageYOffset` and `document.documentElement.scrollTop` both measures the distance of an window top to its topmost visible content in pixel. Are they both same or am I missing something?

Trust `window.pageYOffset` is not supported for IE < 9 but if assuming IE >8 then

- When to use each of them
- difference between them

Comment: There's also [window.scrollY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791336/why-were-window-scrolly-and-window-scrollx-introduced).

Answer (score 21):

Both **window.pageYOffset** and **document.documentElement.scrollTop** returns the same result in all the cases.

Yes, **window.pageYOffset** is not supported below IE 9.

scrollTop() method also can be used to get the vertical scrollbar position of the specific element.

Comment: Apparently, `window.pageYOffset` is slower. A PR in claim: https://github.com/w3c/respec/pull/1685. Someone needs to create a jsperf for this.

Answer (score 12):

The difference between these two can be clearly observed in cross platform mobile application development using Jquery mobile. There,  several pages can be defined in single html pages.

`document.documentElement.scrollTop` will be useful when you are in a particular page and want the value relative to that page where as `window.pageYOffset` only applied to whole html page.

Otherwise like krish has mentioned, results from these two are basically the same.

Answer (score 2):

`document.documentElement.scrollTop` does **NOT** work with Safari nor Apple Products.

`window.pageYOffset` works on all browsers. On browsers that support both functions, they appeared to produce the same values.

Comment: `document.documentElement` seems to be supported in Safari: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement and so does `Element.scrollTop`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop so I'm unsure where the claim that it doesn't work on Safari or other Apple Products comes from.

Comment: lol I'm too interested to know where that comes from? I see many people gives answers like that without proof, you should consider removing your answer as it will confuse a lot of people