# What are the difference between the scrollX and pageXOffset

Tags: javascript

Are the following methods same?

```
window.scrollX  === window.pageXOffset

window.scrollY  === window.pageYOffset
```

If there is no difference, why two methods are introduced?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From MDN:

> The pageXOffset property is an alias for the scrollX property:
>
> ```
> window.pageXOffset == window.scrollX; // always true
> ```
>
> For cross-browser compatibility, use `window.pageXOffset` instead of `window.scrollX`.
>   **Additionally**, older versions of Internet Explorer (< 9) do not support
>   either property and must be worked around by checking other
>   non-standard properties.

Same thing goes for `scrollY` and `pageYOffset`.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollX

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate, but you might also be interested in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791336/why-were-window-scrolly-and-window-scrollx-introduced

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between scrollX/scrollY and pageXOffset/pageYOffset.  One is simply an alias of the other.